# How to get text from attribute with for example regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   1. <a class="click" data-test="CodeMirror-sizer('@aaa', 1)-er">
   2. <a class="click" data-test="CodeMirror-sizer44('@bbb', 2)-fgd">
   3. <a class="click" data-test="CodeMirror-sizer366('@ccc', 2)-gr4f">
   4. <a class="click" data-test="CodeMirror-sizer33('@ddd', 1)-erw">

$(".click").click(function(){
    var text = ???;
   alert(text);
})
```

How to get text from attribute with for example regular expression?
I would receive:

from 1 = @aaa

from 2 = @bbb

from 3 = @ccc

from 4 = @ddd

[**LIVE jsFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7bw/1/)

Comment: Encode the data-attribute as JSON and jQuery will parse that JSON for you

Comment: I don't want to sound like a crazy man or anything but why not put that value into it's own data-item  ?

Answer (score 4):

You could just split on the single quote character and take the second value returned:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).data('test').split("'")[1];
    alert(text);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7bw/2/)**

Comment: This seems a bit fragile, but so does the asker's proprietary data format

Comment: @JanDvorak True, although regex's will probably suffer from the same problem and could add some complexity. I don't know if either approach is necessarily better, it's a matter of taste, really

Comment: You can make this a little less fragile by `.split("'").slice(1, -1).join("'");`, as we know there is only one _JavaScript_ string inside the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    var pattern = /@[a-z]{3}/i
    var text = $(this).attr('data-test')

    alert(text.match(pattern ));
})
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7bw/4/

But it all depends on the pattern, this one just matches and "@" with three characters behind it in the range [a-z]... If you can be more precise with what possible values will be, we can be more precies with capturing them

Comment: `/@\w+/` seems like a reasonable guess, too

Comment: True, in that case mentioning http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp as a reference to what can go in a regEx can be of help to the Asker!

Comment: definitely not. W3schools is a terrible resource. Pick another one.

Comment: Really? It's just the one I had open to do the Fiddle... But if you're right I guess https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+regex+tutorial  will do too! :o)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
var text = $(this).data("test");
alert ( text.match(/^.*\('(.*)\s*'/)[1] );
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `^.*`, is it to move the capture as far to the right as possible?

Comment: @JanDvorak It doesn't use a `?` so it must be making use of the fact greediness will go all the way then backtrack.

Comment: @PaulS. given there are only two apostrophes in the entire matched string, it doesn't really matter if the leftmost or the rightmost match are returned. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7bw/5/

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    var tag = $(this);
   alert(tag.attr('data-test').split('\'')[1]);
})
```